# Is there a way to determine the return-type of a method programmatically?

Tags: c#, methods

I don’t mean overloading. This might include new `Type`s of classes which I haven’t created yet.

EDIT:
I want to create a method which will return a value of the type it gets as a parameter. I can get a parameter of type `object`, but I don’t want to return it that way and then cast, I want the return-value itself to be of the same type as the parameter.

Comment: You should specify the programming language you are referring to. In languages like c# and Java you can use generics like this:  dosomething<T>()

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Please provide an example.

Comment: @Garvin - he did. The question is tagged [tag:c#]

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the tag @ChrisF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a generic method which returns a type to be determined. As long as you declare your new classes correctly then they should work.

There are a number of ways of doing this, a search for [return generic type c#](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GPCK_enGB424GB424&q=return+generic+type+c%23&oq=return+generic+type+c%23&aq=f&aqi=g1g-b5&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=36687l37278l0l37540l3l3l0l0l0l0l193l329l2.1l3l0) turns up several different techniques of varying complexity. Fundamentally you have:

```
public T DoStuff<T>()
{
...
}
```

however, the "..." is the bit that depends on your application.

Comment: I think he should use generic i dont know why ppl said reflection and somebody upvote this isea!!

Answer (score 8):

You could use reflection:

```
var returnType = typeof(SomeClass).GetMethod("SomeMethodName").ReturnType;
```

Comment: Because he said he does'nt want to use overloading so he need to determine the return type of method at runtime and generic methods can help him

Comment: I didn’t notice the question could be understood that way. See edit. (I’m actually using reflection in the method.)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your updates, the method you want will be something like:

```
public T MyMethod<T>(T input)
{
  // DoSomething
  T result = default(T); // Create your instance of T here
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

This should answer your question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.returntype.aspx

Comment: I didn’t notice the question could be understood that way. See edit. (I’m actually using reflection in the method.)

Comment: So... you downvoted me because I answered your original question?

Comment: I didn't.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/939213/ispiro) - I never downvoted anything.

Comment: OK, just making sure. Someone didn't like my answer, I would appreciate some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic type and generic methods to do that
[C# Generic Methods](http://www.dotnetperls.com/generic-method)